# uhttpd rewrite all routes to /

Tags: reactjs, react-router, openwrt, uhttpd

I am trying to set up a react app using react router behind a uhttpd server on an embedded device. Unfortunately I do not know how to forward all subroutes (eg. /foo/bar) back to /

In nginx this is possible using the try_files statement. Is there something similar using uhttpd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I resolved this issue. 
uhttpd have a option "error_page". 
So we must set that option if we decide to use react.

e.g.

```
config uhttpd 'main'
    list listen_http '0.0.0.0:80'
    list listen_http '[::]:80'
    option home '/www'
    option error_page '/index.html'
```